# Media query is not working even it is selected applying

Tags: css, media-queries

Below is my css code and it is not working for the media-query on ipad device for only case of nav a padding, while other code inside @media section new css properties are working fine for ipad device.

```
nav a {
  padding:10px;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { 

    nav a {
        padding:10px; <-- this code is deselected when I see using chrome developer tools, given that I selected ipad view.
    }
 }
```

**EDIT**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably have to add the pseudo-selectors for the anchors:

```
nav a:link, nav a:visited {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you are use these meta tags ?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="YES"/>
```